# GCC + Inline Assembly - Unexpected Segfault on notl

Tags: c, linux, gcc, inline-assembly

Code: http://paste.pocoo.org/show/422081/ (link is 404 missing).

Alright so I'm trying to NOT generic chunks of memory and decided I was done diddling with unwieldy casts and figured I'd drop down into inline assembly (I think it actually improved readability). I've managed to narrow this segfault to one specific function. It's at line 22 of the paste.

Yet it always segfaults. As you can see, str is passed as argv[1].

I can manually do stuff to argv[1] (for example `argv[1][0] = 'q'`) so I'm not entirely sure why that not doesn't work, especially considering that earlier in `nots` it successfully runs `not8` and `not2`. Is there something funky going on that I don't know about? What's going wrong here?

Also a generic code review would be nice; I'm fairly new to C.

Comment: On what computer is this running? You use eax as pointer, but in case you have 64 bit computer/system you have to use rax (maybe not8 and not2 just accidently do not segfault).

Comment: Your not13 function misses a byte of the string(byte 12), you might want to fix that if it was unintended

Comment: @flolo I think that did it! Now I'll let it chug away, and see if my algorithm works ;). @Necrolis Eep! Good eyes.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the link to the pasted code is broken so no-one can tell what was in the code, except by inference from the answer.  The material doesn't look compellingly unique (there are lots of other questions where not enough memory was allocated).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is the `password` variable. You allocate just one element and then you do `password++` in the `for` loop. So the second time you do the loop you are in nowhere land.

The code shows that you are using much too complicated concepts than you master at the moment.

- Don't do inline assembler when you
  don't know yet how to handle
  pointers.
- Don't cast the return of `malloc`.
- `unsigned char` is generally the
  correct type to inspect individual
  bytes of an object.

Comment: Oh darn. I forgot to change that increment of passwd from when it was just a plain long long. Thanks :\ (I should have stepped through the whole thing in the debugger). About casting the return of malloc, doesn't it return a void*? The man pages say so. Why don't you have to cast it? I'll swap over to unsigned char, thanks.

Comment: @corey: in C you can assign a `void*` to any pointer type without a cast. a cast however isn't detrimental in this situation (the compiler should just ignore it).

Comment: @Corey, in C you can assign a `void*` to any other data pointer type. It is made for this. If you cast `malloc` you may hide the fact that you might have forgotten the right include file and thus the return type of `malloc` would default to `int`.